# How to measure the time elapsed since the beginning of an event, and record it in a new dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, trading

I'm trying to measure the time elapsed since the beginning of an event. In this case, I want to know if the volume of bitcoin traded per minute has exceeded a certain threshold. Because what moves the price is the volume. So I want to measure how long there has been significant volume, and record this measurement in a new column.

Here is an example of a dataframe that contains the date in index, the bitcoin price and the volume. I added a column that indicates when the volume has exceeded a certain threshold:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': ['2022-01-11 09:30:00', '2022-01-11 09:31:00', '2022-01-11 09:32:00', '2022-01-11 09:33:00', '2022-01-11 09:34:00', '2022-01-11 09:35:00', ],
    'Volume': ['132', '109', '74', '57', '123', '21'],
    'Volume_cat': ["big_volume", "big_volume", None, None, "big_volume", None],
})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index(['Time'], inplace =True)
df
```

My goal is to have a new column that will display the elapsed time (in seconds) since the last detection of the 'big_volume' event and will reset itself at each new detection.
Here is a line that can be added to the example code:

```
df['delta_big_vol'] = ['60', '120', '180', '240', '60', '120',]
df
```

I have to use the apply() method, but have not found any lambda that would work.
In pseudo code it would look like :

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['delta_xl_vol'] = df.apply(if df["Volume"] > 100 : return(timedelta.total_seconds))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this process, we can't have null values in our "Volume_cat" column:

```
>>> df["Volume_cat"] = df["Volume_cat"].fillna("-")  # This could be any string except "big_volume"
```

This step will help us in the future. We'll remember if our data starts with a `"big_volume"` and also store the index of the first "big_volume" row.

```
>>> idx_of_first_big_volume = df.loc[df["Volume_cat"] == "big_volume"].head(1).index[0]
>>> starts_with_big_volume = idx_of_first_big_volume == df.index[0]
```

Now, let's assign a group to each set of consecutive values in the "Volume_cat" column (consecutive "big_volume" are grouped, and consecutive "-" too).

```
>>> df["Group"] = ((df.Volume_cat != df.Volume_cat.shift()).cumsum())
```

Then, we'll rank each group. Now it's important to group consecutive groups, starting with a "big_volume" group followed by a "-" group, to assign the rank starting from the earliest "big_volume" event up until the last non-new-"big_volume" event (I hope this make sense). Also, notice how the `starts_with_big_volume` help us align the groups properly. If we start with a "big_volume" group, we need to shift the values by subtracting 1:

```
>>> df["rank"] = df.groupby((df["Group"] - 1 * starts_with_big_volume)// 2)["Volume_cat"].rank("first", ascending=False)
```

Finally, we can use our "rank" column and multiply it by 60 to get the number of seconds since the last row with a "big_volume" observation. You can do this in a copy of your dataframe and then include the "delta_big_vol" column in your original dataframe, due to all this new columns in the output.

```
>>> df["delta_big_vol"] = 60 * (df["rank"] - 1)
```

Also, we now can use our `idx_of_first_big_volume` to match your requirement of filling with None all of the observations before the first "big_volume" event:

```
>>> df.loc[:idx_of_first_big_volume, "delta_big_vol"].iloc[:-1] = None
```

This should be the output you get:

```
>>> df
                    Volume  Volume_cat  Group  rank  delta_big_vol
Time                                                              
2022-01-11 09:30:00    132  big_volume      1   1.0            0.0
2022-01-11 09:31:00    109  big_volume      1   2.0           60.0
2022-01-11 09:32:00     74           -      2   3.0          120.0
2022-01-11 09:33:00     57           -      2   4.0          180.0
2022-01-11 09:34:00    123  big_volume      3   1.0            0.0
2022-01-11 09:35:00     21           -      4   2.0           60.0
```

Comment: Hello @aaossa, thank you, your code that works perfectly! Is it possible to improve 2 points :  
1. If the first lines don't contain the event, the column will still start the 'chronometre' and will start with 60 , 120, 180... Can we display None or 0.0 until an event is detected.
2. The code starts the countdown when the event ends. When 2 consecutive events are detected the column displays: 0, 0, 60, 120 ... Is it possible to have 0, 60, 120, 180 ... to have a countdown that takes into account the beginning of the event?

Comment: @Olivier I've updated my answer to match both of your new requirements. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I just noticed, shouldn't the expected output in your question be `[0, 60, 120, 180, 0, 60]`? Let me know to update my answer. If my output is wrong, I just need to change the "delta_big_vol" column to `df["delta_big_vol"] = 60 * df["rank"]`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Let's imagine that a dataframe has a first event on the 4th line, and subsequent events on the 7th and 11th line. The result would be: None, None, None, 0, 60, 120, 0, 60, 120, 180, 0, 60, 120 ...

Comment: Then my answer seems to reach the correct output, were you able to test it?

Comment: that's exactly it, thank you very much. It is late in Europe but tomorrow I will ask more questions on stackoverflow about trading features. If you're interested in the topic, feel free to answer. The features will be based on order flow (volume per price level/pending orders/executed orders/timeliness/iceberg/absoprtion/depletion/trapped traders/LVN...). These are elements used by the algorithms of proprietary trading firms that allow to be more selective on trades while improving timing.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the `Volume` column contains numerical data (yours contains `str` data), you could do

```
threshold = 100
df['Result'] = (
    df.assign(Result=60).Result
      .groupby((df.Volume > threshold).cumsum()).cumsum()
)
```

with the result

```
                     Volume  Volume_cat  Result
Time                                           
2022-01-11 09:30:00     132  big_volume      60
2022-01-11 09:31:00     109  big_volume      60
2022-01-11 09:32:00      74        None     120
2022-01-11 09:33:00      57        None     180
2022-01-11 09:34:00     123  big_volume      60
2022-01-11 09:35:00      21        None     120
```

Or, if you prefer to start at `0`, you could do

```
df['Result'] = (
    df.assign(Result=(df.Volume <= threshold) * 60).Result
      .groupby((df.Volume > threshold).cumsum()).cumsum()
)
```

with the result

```
                     Volume  Volume_cat  Result
Time                                           
2022-01-11 09:30:00     132  big_volume       0
2022-01-11 09:31:00     109  big_volume       0
2022-01-11 09:32:00      74        None      60
2022-01-11 09:33:00      57        None     120
2022-01-11 09:34:00     123  big_volume       0
2022-01-11 09:35:00      21        None      60
```

---

**EDIT** re comment: I'm not completely sure, I've understood correctly.

You could try:

```
threshold = 100
mask = df.Volume > threshold
idx_min = df.index[mask][0]
mask &= ~mask.shift().fillna(False)
df['Result'] = (~mask) * 60
df['Result'] = df.Result.groupby(mask.cumsum()).cumsum().loc[idx_min:]
```

The result for the modified sample frame

```
                     Volume
Time                       
2022-01-11 09:30:00      99
2022-01-11 09:31:00     109
2022-01-11 09:32:00     101
2022-01-11 09:33:00      57
2022-01-11 09:34:00     123
2022-01-11 09:35:00      21
```

is

```
                     Volume  Result
Time                               
2022-01-11 09:30:00      99     NaN
2022-01-11 09:31:00     109     0.0
2022-01-11 09:32:00     101    60.0
2022-01-11 09:33:00      57   120.0
2022-01-11 09:34:00     123     0.0
2022-01-11 09:35:00      21    60.0
```

Comment: Hi @Timus.  Your code works and is simple to implement. Thank you. I have the same remarks as below: is it possible to have 0.0 or None as long as an event has not been detected, and is it possible to start the 'timer' from the moment the event starts and not when it ends? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Olivier I've tried to give it a shot but might have misunderstood your intensions :)